# How to use SparseBooleanArray in Kotlin with CheckBox and RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have found while scrolling Recyclerview, it lost checkboxes states. You can use **SparseBooleanArray** for storing Integer, Boolean values. I found code for Java on the web. But how to do that in Kotlin? Why SparseBooleanArray, what's wrong with HashMap?

Answer (score 1):

`SparseArray` can be used to replace `HashMap` when the key is a primitive type. There are some variants for different key/value types, even though not all of them are publicly available.

Benefits are:

- Allocation-free
- No boxing

Working with a HashMap would work just fine - however it can be slightly more performant to use one of the SparseArray types instead.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java

In order to use SparseBooleanArray in Kotlin, you can use it just like you would from Java:

```
val key = 1
val map = SparseBooleanArray()
map.put(key, true)
val value = map.get(key)
```

If you import the ktx extensions, you can use the Kotlin-style accessors like the following:

```
map[key] = true
val value = map[key]
```

Comment: my question is how to use sparseBooleanArray in Kotlin?

Comment: Do you really need extra dependency to write `map[key]`? "Kotlin allows using any Java methods with the right name and signature as operator overloads and other conventions (invoke() etc.)" (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)

Answer (score 0):

First declare a object of class SparseBooleanArray, like this:

```
val checkBoxStatesArray = SparseBooleanArray()
```

Into onBindViewHolder, put the position on your checkbox:

```
holder.binding.checkBoxAll.isChecked = checkBoxStatesArray.get(position, false)
```

Into your viewHolder, declare the states:

```
val checkbox = binding.checkBoxAll

    init {
        checkbox.setOnClickListener {
            if(!checkBoxStatesArray.get(adapterPosition, false)){
                checkbox.isChecked = true
                checkBoxStatesArray.put(adapterPosition, true)
            }else{
                checkbox.isChecked = false
                checkBoxStatesArray.put(adapterPosition, false)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use adapterPosition or absoluteAdapterPosition